# how to get current api value on every page change using PageView.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

My API gives me a random video link every time I change the page(Like Insta Reel scrolling).

for now its giving me URL link. but `VideoPlayerItem` playing 1 behind.

for example

1st URL is
`Video URL is========> https://github.com/Roy-Tuhin/video_`

2nd URL is
`Video URL is========> https://github.com/Roy-Tuhin/video2222_`

My 1st URL video is playing instead of the second one.

```
class HomeScreenVideoView extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreenVideoView({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<HomeScreenVideoView> createState()  => _HomeScreenVideoViewState();
}

class _HomeScreenVideoViewState extends ConsumerState<HomeScreenVideoView>with BaseScreenView {
  late  HomeVideoScreenViewModel _homeVideoScreenViewModel;                //random video

  late NetworkVideoLikeDislikeViewModel  _networkVideoLikeDislikeViewModel;//like dislike
  late NetworkVideoBookmarkViewModel  _networkVideoBookmarkViewModel;      //bookmark
  late NetworkVideoTimeCapsualViewModel  _networkVideoTimeCapsualViewModel;//timecapsual



  late PageController _pageController;
   String? _videoUrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
    _fetchNewVideo();
    _pageController.addListener(_onPageChanged);
  }

  void _fetchNewVideo() async {
    // Make an API call to fetch a new video
    _homeVideoScreenViewModel = ref.read(homeVideoScreenViewModel);
    _homeVideoScreenViewModel.attachView(this);
    _homeVideoScreenViewModel.getHomeRandomVideo();

    String newVideoUrl = await _homeVideoScreenViewModel.getRandomVideoResponseModel.data?.video ?? "";
    setState(() {
      _videoUrl = newVideoUrl;
      print("Video URL is========================================> $_videoUrl");
    });
  }



  void _onPageChanged() {
    if (_pageController.page == _pageController.page!.round()) {
      // We have reached a new page, fetch a new video
      _fetchNewVideo();
    }
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.removeListener(_onPageChanged);
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
   
      body: PageView.builder(
        itemCount: 100000,
        controller: _pageController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              VideoPlayerItem(
                videoUrl: _videoUrl??""
                
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_fetchNewVideo() method is called after the _pageController has changed the page. As a result, the _videoUrl might not have updated before playing the video, which causes the player to play the previous video instead of the current one.